# ReactJs with reduxjs web app become slow after adding more dat

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have created a custom app which allows user to create proposals by dragging and dropping the components they want. For example - Heading, Text, Image, List, Icons, etc.

I have used the tech stack ReactJs + Redux. I am very near to completion but now I am facing some scalability issues.

*Here is the approach I followed while developing.*

The objective is to save the half-created proposal on the backend, therefore, I thought of the JSON idea that I will be saving all the contents info under 1 reducer and will save that data in DB or etc.

So, I created the JSON like this. Sample JSON below.

```
const initialState = {
  proposalInfoDetails: {
    proposalName: "Sample proposal name",
    documentType: "proposal", // proposal | contract
    dueDate: "2134-01-12T05:00",
    pageSize: "a4", // as | us_letter _ legal
    customer: {
      customer_id: null,
      email: null,
      name: null,
      phone: null,
    }, // array of customers
    vat: "vat_1", // vat types
    pageOrientation: "portrait", // portrait | landscape
    leader: { user_id: null, name: null }, // user_1 | user_2
    referredBy: "",
    documentDescription: "Sample document description",
    currency: "inr", // select all currencies from dropdown,
    proposalSequenceText: "Sample Co.",
    proposalSequenceNumber: "000",
    emails: {
      cc: ["info@abc.com", "info@abc.com"],
      bcc: ["info@abc.com", "info@abc.com"],
    },
    proposalAmount: 0,
    contactDetails: {
      contact_id: null,
      name: null,
      phone: null,
      email: null,
    },
  },
  pages: [],
  generalNotes: [],
  generalActions: [],
  parentPageStyles: {},
  parentStyles: {
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    opacity: 1,
    marginTop: 0,
    marginBottom: 0,
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginRight: 0,
  },
  overrideFonts: {
    h1: {
      fullName: "Heading 1",
      fontFamily: "arial",
      fontSize: "18px",
      fontWeight: 600,
      color: "#000000",
      changed: false,
    },
    h2: {
      fullName: "Heading 2",
      fontFamily: "arial",
      fontSize: "18px",
      fontWeight: 600,
      color: "#000000",
      changed: false,
    },
    h3: {
      fullName: "Heading 3",
      fontFamily: "arial",
      fontSize: "18px",
      fontWeight: 600,
      color: "#000000",
      changed: false,
    },
    h4: {
      fullName: "Heading 4",
      fontFamily: "arial",
      fontSize: "18px",
      fontWeight: 600,
      color: "#000000",
      changed: false,
    },
    h5: {
      fullName: "Heading 5",
      fontFamily: "arial",
      fontSize: "18px",
      fontWeight: 600,
      color: "#000000",
      changed: false,
    },
    h6: {
      fullName: "Heading 6",
      fontFamily: "arial",
      fontSize: "18px",
      fontWeight: 600,
      color: "#000000",
      changed: false,
    },
    p: {
      fullName: "Paragraph",
      fontFamily: "arial",
      fontSize: "18px",
      fontWeight: 600,
      color: "#000000",
      changed: false,
    },
    h: {
      fullName: "Hyperlink",
      fontFamily: "arial",
      fontSize: "18px",
      fontWeight: 600,
      color: "#000000",
      changed: false,
    },
    t: {
      table: {
        fullName: "Table font",
        fontFamily: "arial",
        fontSize: "18px",
        fontWeight: 600,
        color: "#000000",
        changed: false,
      },
    },
  },
  undoHistory: [],
  redoHistory: [],
  loading: false,
  zoom: "100",
  open: null,
};
```

**Pages** is of type array which further contains the no. of rows -> no. or columns -> no. of elements -> each element with type and its CSS (Js format inline).

Now, App loops through the page array to display the data.

Templates of components are present in the application which the program reads and pushes the specific component based on what is present in the pages JSON.

**ISSUE**

As Apps loop through the array to display data, therefore, the app becomes very slow after adding a lot of content.

I am not sure what's wrong but I think it is because of the loop. But at the same time, I cannot think of any other approach.

***APY HELP IS HIGHLY APPRECIATED, I AM STRUGGLING WITH THIS FOR A VERY LONG TIME.***

Comment: I have a question about your `customer`. you commented `// array of customers` but you have curly brackets `{}` and structures it as an object not as an array as array use `[]`. and if that would be an array then it should be called `customers` as a plural as there could be more then 1.

Comment: As for the lag - I can not be sure but I can give you some suggestion for some improvements - split up the code. If you store everything in 1 reducer then updating 1 thing in it will cost every component, that uses this reducer, to re-render. If you split it up to, lets say, 10 reducers then updating 1 will only re-render a component, or few, that uses data from that reducer. so, for exmaple: adding one more customer wont cause to re-render your `pages`. And it becomes easier to read and re-use. Look at it as a single responsobility - a reducer of `customers` shouldint know of with `pages`

Comment: The comment array of customers is a type, This was changed but I forgot to update the comment. Thanks for telling.

Also, let me think how can i split my reducer. Thanks for suggestion. @Lith

Comment: If you can provide more information, we might be able to help. How does the reducer look like? How are your components rendered? How does the main loop look like? This question is missing vital information.